# working with php session variables for an xmlrpc client in php

Tags: php, session, variables, xml-rpc, ussd

am working on a menu-drived [USSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USSD_Gateway) app developed in php. My app communicates with a telecom's ussd server using xmlrpc client-server interactions. so each time a mobile user sends a request to the telecom network which inturn re-routes that request to my php through the telecoms USSD gateway/server, my websever(apache) interpretes each request as an entirely new session, so the session variable values i set for one request are not passed on the next request even if it's still the same session. Am wondering why this is so and how i can solve this problem, so that i have my session values set for as long as the session is not ended. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your server is probably sending a `Set-Cookie:` header, but is the client accepting the cookie, and sending back a `Cookie:` header with subsequent requests?  If the client doesn't support cookies, then the default cookie-based PHP session mechanism isn't going to work.

Comment: good point about the header - added

Answer (score 1):

How do you define "session"?

The XML-RPC client in this case needs to inform the server that it has a [session](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) - this is usually done silently by a cookie (PHP will send a Set-Cookie on session start with the id), or by a GET parameter in the URL. You could even do it yourself within the RPC response/request (although you'd have to write your own session handlers to extract the session ID).

Without that identifier - your server will treat each new request as a new session.

Comment: Thanks HorusKol, let me do that.